# Why MarkerCluster dosen't work

Tags: leaflet

I want yo use **markercluster** in *leaflet* so i added in the head this code :

```
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-markercluster/v0.4.0/leaflet.markercluster.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-markercluster/v0.4.0/MarkerCluster.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-markercluster/v0.4.0/MarkerCluster.Default.css' rel='stylesheet' />
```

however when i try to store markers on the markercluster and then display it the map i get an empty map :

```
<script type="text/javascript"'>
    var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([40.7128, -74.0060], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
maxZoom: 18,
id: 'mapbox.streets',
accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoiYWhtZWQ5NCIsImEiOiJjaml3OWx4YnYyaDRsM3FxbWFya3dxdHI4In0.Z7ODiHmNEFY2wAPFD6mX1w'
}).addTo(mymap);

var marker = L.marker([40.7128,-74.0060]);
var markerClusters = L.markerClusterGroup();
markerClusters.addLayer(marker)
mymap.addLayer(markerClusters)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved my problem by installing them (*css* and *js*) instead in my computer:

```
npm install leaflet.markercluster
```

Comment: Leaflet.markercluster plugin version 0.4.0 (as shown in your question code) is for Leaflet 0.x. For Leaflet 1.x, you should use the plugin version 1+.